# Should I practice reading or writing kana first?

Tags: discussion, learning

I'm revising the kana in preparation to study at university, and I'd like to know whether it's better to practice writing them first, or reading them? Does reading naturally follow writing, or vice versa? Or am I making a basic mistake in trying to short circuit the process because the two skills should be given equal priority and learned in tandem?

Comment: Once you can write kana, you'll be able to remember how to read them as well.